# Raspbian Jessie GUI hangs after running matchbox-keyboard

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, touchscreen

I have Raspberry Pi 2B, touchscreen, Raspbian Jessie 2016-05-10 with default LXDE desktop environment, installed matchbox-keyboard.

When I run matchbox-keyboard it works correctly, but Raspbian GUI hangs (I can't open any folder in the file manager and if any folder is opened it also hangs and can't be closed).

After closing matchbox-keyboard there is an error in the terminal:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
after 5077 requests (5077 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Also Raspberry doesn't turn off, it hangs after shutdown.

This error appears both with touchscreen and simple LCD monitor.

Tell me please how to fix this error? Or how to restart graphical interface (if it will help)? Are there any analog of matchbox-keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with the File Manager freezing when I open matchbox-keyboard.
What I do is open a Text file & then matchbox-keyboard, write the text, close the matchbox-keyboard and then close the File Manager twice. Both times click 'End Process' in the DialogueBox. It takes a few seconds for the first Dialogue Box to appear. Once the File Manager has closed I can reopen a new File Manager & everything returns to normal until the next time I want to use the matchbox-keyboard.
A lasting solution would be very helpful, Walter

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very interesting solution! I'll try it! By the way I tried to use **florence** screen keyboard (`sudo apt-get install florence`). It works but crashes when I press any button. May be it will work for you? Also there is an [useful article - setup raspberrypi tablet](https://fredfire1.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/setup-raspberrypi-tablet-official-raspberry-pi-7%E2%80%B3-touchscreen-display-raspberrypi/). The **kvkbd** keyboard (`sudo apt-get install -y kvkbd`) is also suggested in this article. I have not already tried to use it, but it may be working.

Comment: Also if you use non default desktop environment (I use LXDE) there are another screen keyboards for such desktop environments as is shown there: [raspbian tablet with Ubuntu Mate](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Tablet/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Alexander. Will try them later & comment on them. Note that I have changed my post slightly by adding that I open the matchbox-keyboard after opening the Text file.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the easiest working solution for me is to instal **xvkbd** (`sudo apt-get install xvkbd`). I successfully installed it and it works without any problem on my Raspberry Pi. Also its size is much less than size of **kvkbd** (more than 200 Mb).

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not an answer to the question.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.  You can ask questions via the [Ask Question page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), linked top right.